# Selecting elements in a matrix that satisfy only the specified condition but nothing else in R

Tags: r, plyr

I have a matrix 'mat' with two rows of the following form:

```
mat:

1  0
1  2
1  3
1  5
1  9 
1  4
1  7
1  11
1  8
2  3
2  4
2  2
3  9
3  0
4  0
5  0
5  13
6  22
6  0
```

I define a variale called 'neg' which only includes the number 0.

```
neg <- 0
```

I would like to select those elements in the first column of the matrix that have ONLY 'neg' in their second column.

So instead of saying mat[mat[,1]%in%0,1] which would select every number in the first row that has at least one 0 in the second, I would like to get only those that have ONLY 0, in this example only 4 would be selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `plyr` for this. But first read your data:

```
dat = read.csv(textConnection("1  0
1  2
1  3
1  5
1  9 
1  4
1  7
1  11
1  8
2  3
2  4
2  2
3  9
3  0
4  0
5  0
5  13
6  22
6  0"), header = FALSE, sep = "")
```

And after loading plyr, I want to find the unique categories in `V1` which have only values equal to `neg` in column `V2`, resulting in a list: `true_values`.

```
require(plyr)
neg = 0
test = ddply(dat, .(V1), summarise, bool = all(V2 == neg))
>     test
  V1  bool
1  1 FALSE                                                                  
2  2 FALSE                                                                  
3  3 FALSE                                                                  
4  4  TRUE                                                                  
5  5 FALSE                                                                  
6  6 FALSE 
true_values = test[["V1"]][test[["bool"]]]
> true_values
[1] 4
```

Once we have this list, we can subset the original dataset:

```
> dat[dat[["V1"]] %in% true_values,]
   V1 V2
15  4  0
```

---

Or alternatively, we could generate a boolean vector directly specifying which elements to select from `dat`:

```
test = ddply(dat, .(V1), mutate, bool = all(V2 == neg))
```

...and perform the subset:

```
> dat[test[["bool"]],]
   V1 V2
15  4  0
```

Comment: Which was also not specified in your question. Add more detail if you need a more specific answer.

Comment: well neg can be a vector say neg=0,1,3,5,7 then I would like to test for all values of neg

Comment: then just replace `V2 == neg` with `V2 %in% neg`. (If you needed `neg` to be a vector why give `neg = 0` as an example...)

Answer (score 0):

this works only for your specific case, but you could use tapply:

```
as.numeric(names(which(tapply(a[,2],a[,1],sum)==0)))
```

If you think of the first column as factors, then tapply computes the sum in the second column for each level of the factor in the first.

and for the multiple value case, something like this -- admittedly ugly -- should work:

```
as.numeric(names(which(tapply(dat[,2],dat[,1],FUN=function(x){all(unique(x)%in%neg & length(x)==length(neg))}))))
```